# Can't connect IBOutlet in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder

I'm having a weird experience. I create any type of iPhone application, add a UIViewController with Xib file. I can edit the xib file with controls and see them rendered if I run. Now i'm trying to add a few IBOutlets to the controller, so I add them to the .h file, synthesize on the .m file. Then i head over to Interface Builder to connect the outlets. I drag the UILabel to the UIView, and then i try to connect the File Owner (which my custom UIViewController), but all that i can select when i try to connect to the UILabel is "view", which is obviosly wrong. So I'm not able to connect IBOutlets to their controls in Interface Builder.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the code of your @interface block...  did you save the .h file?

Comment: import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface gg : UIViewController { 
IBOutlet UILabel *label; 
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label; 

@end

Comment: Any idea how can we resolve the same for xCode4?

Comment: Also make sure to create Cocoa Touch class under iOS -> Source section, I created swift files and wondered for sometime, and making sure the class names match in the interface builder (ie view controllers).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I did a combination of the things in this thread and I finally had success.

In Interface builder (not xcode)

1. File->Reload All Class Files
2. File->Read Class Files (select MyClass.h)
3. Reconnect File's Owner by
   a. Setting the Class to "MyClass"
   b. Reconnecting the View to the File's Owner's View

Everything is back to normal now.  Weird.

Hope this helps more than it confuses ;-)

Comment: Files tab doesn't have Reload all Class Files

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem.

Fixed it by double checking my File's Owner "Class" attribute on the Identity inspector.

Answer (score 6):

In Interface Builder File->Read Class Files, and point it to your File's Owner's class.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the File's Owner is correctly set to your custom UIViewController and that you've **saved** your `.h` file after having added the `IBOutlet` keyword to the instance variable *and* property?

Comment: I am positive the type of the File Owner is the same as the custom UIViewController. I'm positive I have saved the .h file as well. Here is what the .h file looks like:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface gg : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

Comment: That's just weird then. Have you tried deleting the `.xib`, `.h` and `.m` files and re-creating them?

Comment: yeah. i tried all of that. rebooting too. weirder thing is my older projects don't give me that behavior, but new projects i create give me that experience. very strange.

Comment: even if i check the connections tab on my custom view controller, i don't see the new outlets that i've added to the .h file

Comment: does it help to add that none of the supportive "intellisense" hints are not working in the .m file.

Comment: Do you have any compile errors or warnings? Usually, when auto-complete doesn't work for me, I messed up the brackets or parentheses somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Did you make sure you are defining your outlets in your .h file as the appropriate type?  If you are trying to connect a text field in IB, then your .h file should look something like...

```
IBOutlet UITextField    *MyTextField;
```

Make sure the type is UITextField (or UITextView, etc).  If you type them as NSString or anything the is not appropriate, then you can't connect them in Interface Builder....

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for the LONGEST. Changing my File's Owner "Type" to "MyClassViewController" instead of "UIViewController" in the Class identity window fixed my issue. It makes sense because as the File's owner type is UIViewController it's only going to show those properties specific to the base class. Changing the type to MyClassViewController gives access to it's outlets and all inherited instances. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had pretty much the same problem as you did. I don't know if you solved your problem yet but mine was that I changed all the classes' names, including the viewcontroller, but the file's owner's name remain unchanged. 
  So, I double clicked File's owner -> click i in the window opened -> change the name in the Class field to the new viewcontroller name. Then it worked.
  Maybe you want to try it again and see if it works.
  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you failed to connect your UI controls to code via Right-click (or CTRL) -> dropped down list, there is another way. In interface builder,  press & hold CTRL, drug mouse from   "File's Owner" in the Main window of Interface Builder to your UI control (label, button, etc). The dpopdown list with all defined by you Outlets will be appered. Just choice needed one!

Comment: Yeah, we know that solution, but the problem is that the outlet was not showing up in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`File->Read Class Files (select MyClass.h)` Did the job for me.

Comment: Hey,
I also have the same problem,but cannot find the option for "Read Class Files" in FIle menu please help..
I am using xcode 4.

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal did you ever find the option in xCode 4. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Xcode 5.1 did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

`XCode -> Product -> Clean`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I just tried diatrevolo's suggestion: Click File, then Read Class Files, and point to your File's s Owner class.

This fixed it for me. I would +1 diatrevolo, but I don't have any reputation yet...

Answer (score 1):

kills me every time, but sometimes if you just close and reopen xcode, things are fixed... Just happened to me with this exact problem...

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had created a `MyUITextView` extending the `UITextView` and X-Code would'nt connect.
My workaround was to use `UITextView` in IBOutlet temporarily to connect/link and then change to my custom view.

So I changed.

```
IBOutlet MyUITextView *tv;
```

to

```
IBOutlet UITextView *tv;
```

and then connected/ linked. 
Once connected, I changed my OBOutlet back to MyUITextView

```
IBOutlet MyUITextView *tv;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote out

```
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
```

in the UIViewController text file then connected from the file to the label in the storyboard, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know exactly why it doesn't automatically make the IBOutlet connections, but i found a workaround. I had to manually add the outlets through the Library in Interface Builder for my customer view controller. If anyone finds the fix to make it automatically read from the .h file (like its supposed to), I'd be very appreciative if they posted it.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newbie at this, and I had the same problem.  I went to try diatrevolo's suggestion, and, in doing so, found out what was causing my problem.  I had originally created my ViewController somewhere random in the project hierarchy, and then moved them into the classes folder.  This meant that the actual files were not in the classes folder, but the project thought that they were, so IB was looking in the wrong place.  I moved the actual files in to the actual classes file with Finder, and then deleted and readded them in the project.  Then everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

After I localized some XIB files, the views did not react to any updates made in Interface Builder. Simple solution was **to delete the app from the simulator / device**. The next Build&Run updated the application correctly.

This only happened while deploying the app via XCode on the simulator. Seems like XCode is trying to optimize the build and gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble here too, and what ended up working for me was to build the app prior to opening Interface Builder.  Voodoo!