# UIView with UITableview and UIImageview, accessing UITableview with reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

[image]

I have searched now for a very long time without any success.

I have an `UIView` which includes an `UITableView` and an `UIImageview`.

I need this because otherwise the `UITableView` can't be resized.

So now I cant use the `reloadData` method to reload some Data of the `TableView`.

I tried everything, but I can't connect the `IBOutlet(UITableview)` with the controller.

So here is my code for the ViewController:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet UITableView* tableview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* tableview;
```

Please help so my headaches will disappear soon

**EDIT :**

I think its this issue but I use Xcode 4.1: [Can't connect IBOutlet in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder)

**UPDATE :**

I just removed the faulty `UIView` and its Controller and copied the code back in...

Finally it worked, took me about 5 hours until I knew that it wasn´t my fault...

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of your code would help, but does the following exist in your .h file?

```
{
   UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

And don't forget to synthesize the property in your .m file.

Comment: Yes i have this in my h. file....
still its not working. Really Im going nuts....

Comment: I have uploaded a pic of my Xib files, MainViewController has the Tableview and Imageview in it...

Comment: I think its this issue but I use Xcode 4.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder