# Interface Builder Not Responding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a nearly ready project in Cocoa, for which I want to add a couple more things. I added an

```
-(IBAction) methodname : (NSString *) param1
```

in the .h file and the corresponding in the .m file.

However, in IB, there is no display of methodname, thus I cannot connect this method to a button. In other words, when I right click in the controller object in IB, methodname is not there.

I have tried to clean all targets and rebuild the project, however to no avail. Any ideas how I can 'refresh' IB so that the addition of a new method is realized?

Thanks!

Comment: im not sure but this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change this to

```
-(IBAction) methodname : (id) sender
```

and try.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the sender part.. Thanks for that.

However, just another quick question.. If I want to add more parameters other than the sender, can I do it? Is it done in the normal way :(type) name ??

I have tried to add the other parameters after the (id) sender, but this resulted in the method not being displayed in IB. Thanks!

Comment: Additional information: You can pass other parameters via other methods, e.g. use `tag` , use `NSUserDefaults`, use variables in App Delegates, etc.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, thanks for reading my mind! I got shown your answer as soon as I hit the enter key.