# Connecting IBOutlet to UITextView makes UITextView invisible

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have checked thoroughly for a solution to this (notably here: [Can't connect IBOutlet in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder)) but cannot see the solution. I have a `UITextView` that I am using as a text area in a form. I have connected it to this class member in IB:

IBOutlet UITextView *notes;

here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface U2MIDetailController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIButton *confirmButton;
IBOutlet UITextView *notes;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* notes;
@property ABRecordRef personObject;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

@end
```

and my .m, the relevant bits:

```
    @synthesize notes;


    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //set up delegates for keyboard hiding

        notes.delegate = self;

        notes.text = @"Notes";


  ...
}
```

In the links I've found some have solved this issue by checking the File's Owner "Class" attribute on the Identity inspector. How do I do that? I have attached a pic of the hierarchy which looks correct to me, the identity inspector doesn't jump out at me either as having any suspicious properties.

[image: Hierarchy]

Here is a shot of the storyboard:

[image]

and here is how it looks int he simulator:

[image]

Comment: click on `Detail Controller - Detail` then go to `Identity inspector` and check `Custom Class -> Class`.

Comment: Ok yeah that looks right, it's this same detail controller class.

Comment: it means your `file's owner class` is proper.

Comment: proper as in correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct. may be there is another issue with `textView`.

Comment: check your scrollview frame size

Comment: post your screen shot

Comment: scroll view frame size is 1000.

Comment: did able to scroll your view @FrankConry

Answer (score 0):

check your scrollview frame either it is fit to frame or not. put blackground color you know where you did mistake

Comment: putting background doesn't help, still invisible. I can edit it in the simulator though.