# Connecting IBOutlet in Newly Created .Swift File

Tags: ios, xcode

I wrote some code in Swift for an iOS app in XCode (7.1.1) and I can't use the drag and drop in the interface builder for the outlet I want to connect. I tried to do it manually too but the outlet didn't show up in the reference collection when I tried to do it.

I did see this answer:
[Can't connect IBOutlet in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder)

But this appears to be for Objective-C/older versions of XCode. The way I have it right now is I have my main DataViewController.swift file and then I created a PhotoViewer.swift file (it's just an example so the code doesn't really matter it's pretty simple). I used the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PhotoViewer: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewerButton: UIButton!

    func loadPhotoUI() {
        viewerButton.setTitle("View Photos", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

The viewerButton does not show up as an option and when I open up the story board and try to Ctrl-Click and drag to the file on the right side, it doesn't let me drop it in.

If I try it on the DataViewController.swift file (the one that was there when I started the initial template), it still works.

I'm guessing I just need to change a setting on the new file but I can't seem to figure that out. I basically will be using the classes functions in the DataViewController like:

```
let photoClass = PhotoViewer()
self.photoClass.loadPhotoUI()
```

etc etc. I'm just wanting to keep everything super organized.

I'm obviously a bit of a noob at Swift so thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you change Class to PhotoViewer for this ViewController in storyboard in Identity Inspector?

Comment: Please check in storyboard in Identity Inspector for your viewController and the class name "PhotoViewer" are same or not

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewController in your Storyboard needs to be linked to your Swift file.

You have to change the Class to "PhotoViewer" in your Identify Inspector in your Storyboard Viewcontroller:

[image]