# XCode: I can't set the delegate of a tableView (IB or programmatically)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa, tableview

I don't know what happens, but I can't set the delegate of a tableview anymore either via interface builder or programmatically.

[image: Can't set the delegate]

In interface builder, the delegate link for the tableView is gone, and programmatically, even if I set `tableview.delegate = self`, the method (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) is not called.

This is the first time it happens to me. It occurs only in my current project. On a new project, there is not this problem.
Does anyone know why this can happen?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2261626/6414904, cleaning your build and restarting xcode would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect an outlet for the tableview and then add try the following in your view controller class:

```
self.yourTableView.delegate = self
self.yourTableView.dataSource = self
```

Make sure you've added UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate with the View controller definition. Like this,

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Comment: Reading the question, he knows how to connect a tableView and it seems like an xCode bug

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, go to your View controller window make sure your Utilities window is open and looking at Connections Inspector (rightmost icon)
Now click on the ViewController icon in the ViewController's window header and it'll show you all connections.
Now click on your tableView to select it and cntl-drag from tableview to VC icon in header.  Delegate should be unchecked so select it.  I think you need both the Delegate and DataSource to be connected.  a blob against each and normal service should be resumed.

Comment: One further thought, check your tableview method signatures.  If cellForRowAtIndexPath is called but didSelectRowAtIndexPath not.  Create a new didSelectRowAtIndexPath and make sure the one you were using matches.  Make sure it is autocompleting when you add it.