# UIButton Label Needs to be Updated – How can I Reference It?

Tags: ios, swift, reference, uibutton

In a game project, a grid of buttons in the the storyboard needs to have their labels updated to reflect game state. Effectively, a button with an image background represents a scrabble tile; at different times the buttons display different tiles (or no value).

I can't treat an IBButton as an outlet. And I can't create a reference to the button unless it's connected to something in the ViewController. I don't see any way to achieve my goal: when a tile changes, change the letter displayed on the button.

This is trivial in any number of programming environments, presentation technologies. If I could at least loop through all the UI elements on the screen, looking for an identifier, I could probably do that. But even that seems to be impossible, at least in the references I have found.

Comment: You said "I can't create a reference to the button unless it's connected to something in the ViewController."   why ?

Comment: because a connection requires an IBOutlet, and and IBButton is not permitted. Specifically, to make changes without interaction with the object, it must conform to IBOutlet.

Comment: You can still link the UIButton from the storyboard to the VC as you would do for a label

Comment: To an IBAction. Not an IBOutlet.

Comment: No, also to an IBOutlet, try have a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks for sending me back to look at that. It does work, which you would hope... the declaration @IBOutlet var button : IBButton was showing a compile error. But it's not now. I think, on my old MBP, the compiler takes a while to catch up... Thanks again.

Comment: this is a real duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746281/cant-connect-iboutlet-in-interface-builder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing text of UIButton programmatically swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326296/changing-text-of-uibutton-programmatically-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a connection from the storyboard

```
 @IBOutlet weak private var button1: UIButton!
```

Then change the title with

```
button1.setTitle("new title", for: .normal)
```